# How can i fix this(non-static method)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an error.

This is for search in database:

```
UserBankAccount toUserBankAccount = ctx.UserBankAccounts.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Currency == fromUserBankAccount.Currency && x.UserId == toUser.UserId);
```

The exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a
>   target.'

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: What happens if you just do ctx.UserBankAccounts.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.Currency == fromUserBankAccount.Currency && x.UserId == toUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault()?

Answer (score 0):

I had instances where this exception was caused, because of the variables in the LINQ being null. Please check if `fromUserBankAccount`, `fromUserBankAccount.Currency`, `toUser`, `toUser.UserId` are not null at any point.